# Undefined reference for TLSv1_1_client_method though 'nm' says otherwise

Tags: c, linux, openssl

In my SSL client code, on trying to compile I get an undefined reference error on using `TLSv1_1_client_method()`. If I don't have the TLS method, the linking is fine. On running `ldd` on the binary I see:

```
%ldd client_sim_ssl
libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 
libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10
```

Now, if I check `nm` for `/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10` :

```
%nm /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 | grep  TLSv1_1_client_method
0000000000030d30 T TLSv1_1_client_method
```

OpenSSL version installed : `OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014`

Why the undefined reference error when the library it links to has the definition? What is the missing piece?

EDIT 1:

I had logged off the system I was working on. In my experiment in upgrading the version  - openSSL 1.0.1g, I think, I have messed with libraries. SSH connection is having problems. :-(

> ssh root@10.200.2.197
>   ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

May be my original problem is also related to this?

I will update the post shortly on more details as I fix SSH connection issue.

EDIT 2:

My system is RHEL 6.1. For SSH issue had to re install OpenSSL rpm from CD for there was version mismatch error from `ssh`. With this OpenSSL reinstallation, libraries have been set right in `/usr/lib/` and  `/usr/lib64/`. Now I don't get to see `TLSv1_1_client_method()` with `nm`.

I must have put in libraries from 1.0.1g into `/usr/lib64/' and thus resulted in`nm` showing TLS method. And while compiling it was using other versions? Not sure.

Comment: Can you post the exact linker error?

Comment: A complete reproducible source plus the exact compilation command should be nice. The source should not contain much more than a call to the offending function.

Comment: I will update the post shortly.

Comment: The `nm` shows different symbol table. Try `objdump -T`.

Comment: Its usually a bad idea to simply replace the system's version of OpenSSL.